# How to use values from multiple Html Checkboxes in SQL query?

Tags: html, arrays

I have this dropdown list with multiple checkboxes, the one on left helps to check all Aisles in group by one click. All checkboxes has values i need to use in SQL Query to look them up.
How i can save all the values from this dropdown in similar format like: `'099','101','105','106','202'`
So I can then use it in SQL query as list of values.

```
 SELECT * FROM table   WHERE aisle IN ( '099','101','105','106','202')
```

I think it should store all the values inside the `selectBox` after i press submit, but the text value of `selectBox` what is `<option>Select Aisles</option>` never changes, even with just one selected box.
I know that my code is pretty much naked, without any functions for that SQL query, as i believe i am able to do that one. Only issue is I do not know how to capture those values from all checkboxes.
Thank you for advice.

**Edit:** I manage to figured out most of the issues with help from @Adam P. but it is not working as I would like.

1. Now, when i submit the form it prints those aisle numbers in to text field. I just do not know how to print all those values without `,` on the end, after last Aisle number.
2. Second issue is since i added this function there it is not closing the dropdown menu after it was submited.

   Dropdown Test
        
        
            h1 {
                color: green;
            }
            .multipleSelection {
                width: 320px;
                background-color: #BCC2C1;
            }
            .selectBox {
                position: relative;
            }
            .selectBox select {
                width: 100%;
                font-weight: bold;
            }
            .overSelect {
                position: absolute;
                left: 0;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
            }
            #checkBoxes {
                display: none;
                border: 1px #8DF5E4 solid;
            }
            #checkBoxes label {
                display: inline-block;
            }
            #checkBoxes label:hover {
                background-color: #4F615E;
            }

   ```
    <form id="aisle_selection" method="post" action="" >
        <div class="multipleSelection">
            <div class="selectBox" 
                onclick="showCheckboxes()">
                <select>
                    <option  id="aisle_selectbox">Select Aisle</option>
                </select>
                <div class="overSelect"></div>
            </div>

            <div id="checkBoxes">

                <div>
                    <table>
                <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-md-2">Zone</th>
                            <th class="col-md-10">Aisle</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody><tr><td><input onClick="selectAllLe(this,'class_LE')" type="checkbox" value=""><span>LE<span></span></span></td><td class="checkBOX">
                            <label><input class="class_LE" type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="001" value="001"><span>1</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="002"value="002"><span>2</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="003" value="003"><span>3</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="096" value="096"><span>96</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="097" value="097"><span>97</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="098" value="098"><span>98</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="099" value="099"><span>99</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="990" value="990"><span>990</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="991" value="991"><span>991</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="992" value="992"><span>992</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="993" value="993"><span>993</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="994" value="994"><span>994</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="995" value="995"><span>995</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="996" value="996"><span>996</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="997" value="997"><span>997</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="998" value="998"><span>998</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_LE"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="999" value="999"><span>999</span></label>
                            <hr style="margin-top: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 0.05em; border-top: 3px dotted #bbb;">
                        </td></tr><tr><td><input onClick="selectAllA(this,'class_A')" type="checkbox" value=""><span>A<span></span></span></td><td class="checkBOX">
                            <label><input class="class_A"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="100" value="100"><span>100</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_A"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="101" value="101"><span>101</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_A"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="102" value="102"><span>102</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_A"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="103" value="103"><span>103</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_A"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="104" value="104"><span>104</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_A"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="105" value="105"><span>105</span></label>
                            <hr style="margin-top: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 0.05em; border-top: 3px dotted #bbb;">
                        </td></tr><tr><td><input onClick="selectAllB1(this,'class_B1')" type="checkbox" value=""><span>B1<span></span></span></td><td class="checkBOX">
                            <label><input class="class_B1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="106" value="106"><span>106</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_B1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="107" value="107"><span>107</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_B1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="108" value="108"><span>108</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_B1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="109" value="109"><span>109</span></label>
                            <hr style="margin-top: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 0.05em; border-top: 3px dotted #bbb;">
                        </td></tr><tr><td><input onClick="selectAllB2(this,'class_B2')" type="checkbox" value=""><span>B2<span></span></span></td><td class="checkBOX">
                            <label><input class="class_B2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="110" value="110"><span>110</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_B2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="111" value="111"><span>111</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_B2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="112" value="112"><span>112</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_B2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="113" value="113"><span>113</span></label>
                            <hr style="margin-top: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 0.05em; border-top: 3px dotted #bbb;">
                        </td></tr><tr><td><input onClick="selectAllC1(this,'class_C1')" type="checkbox" value=""><span>C1<span></span></span></td><td class="checkBOX">
                            <label><input class="class_C1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="114" value="114"><span>114</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_C1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="115" value="115"><span>115</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_C1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="116" value="116"><span>116</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_C1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="117" value="117"><span>117</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_C1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="118" value="118"><span>118</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_C1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="119" value="119"><span>119</span></label>
                            <hr style="margin-top: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 0.05em; border-top: 3px dotted #bbb;">
                        </td></tr><tr><td><input onClick="selectAllC2(this,'class_C2')" type="checkbox" value=""><span>C2<span></span></span></td><td class="checkBOX">
                            <label><input class="class_C2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="120" value="120"><span>120</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_C2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="121" value="121"><span>121</span></label>
                            <hr style="margin-top: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 0.05em; border-top: 3px dotted #bbb;">
                        </td></tr><tr><td><input onClick="selectAllD1(this,'class_D1')" type="checkbox" value=""><span>D1<span></span></span></td><td class="checkBOX">
                            <label><input class="class_D1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="200" value="200"><span>200</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="201" value="201"><span>201</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="202" value="202"><span>202</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="203" value="203"><span>203</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="204" value="204"><span>204</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="205" value="205"><span>205</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D1"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="206" value="206"><span>206</span></label>
                            <hr style="margin-top: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 0.05em; border-top: 3px dotted #bbb;">
                        </td></tr><tr><td><input onClick="selectAllD2(this,'class_D2')" type="checkbox" value=""><span>D2<span></span></span></td><td class="checkBOX">
                            <label><input class="class_D2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="207" value="207"><span>207</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="208" value="208"><span>208</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="209" value="209"><span>209</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="210" value="210"><span>210</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="211" value="211"><span>211</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="212" value="212"><span>212</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D2"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="213" value="213"><span>213</span></label>
                            <hr style="margin-top: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 0.05em; border-top: 3px dotted #bbb;">
                        </td></tr><tr><td><input onClick="selectAllD3(this,'class_D3')" type="checkbox" value=""><span>D3<span></span></span></td><td class="checkBOX">
                            <label><input class="class_D3"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="214" value="214"><span>214</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D3"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="215" value="215"><span>215</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D3"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="216" value="216"><span>216</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D3"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="217" value="217"><span>217</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D3"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="218" value="218"><span>218</span></label>
                            <label><input class="class_D3"  type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="219" value="219"><span>219</span></label>
                            <hr style="margin-top: 0.05em; margin-bottom: 0.05em; border-top: 3px dotted #bbb;">

                        </td></tr><tr><td><span>Abnormal<span></span></span></td><td>
                            <label><input type="checkbox" name="aisle[]" id="900" value="900"><span>900</span></label></td></tr></tbody>
                    </table>
                    <div> <button type="reset">Reset</button>  <button type="button" id="confirmQ" name="confirmQ">Confirm</button> </div>

                </div>
        </div>
             </div>
    </form>
    <?php
     echo($_POST);
    ?>
    <div id="results"></div>
    <script>

        $('#confirmQ').on('click',function(){
          var x = $("#aisle_selection").serializeArray();
          $("#aisle_selectbox").empty();
          $.each(x, function(i, field){         
            $("#aisle_selectbox").append(field.value + ", ");
          });
        });


        function selectAllLe(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('class_LE');
            for(var i in checkboxes)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
        function selectAllA(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('class_A');
            for(var i in checkboxes)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
        function selectAllB1(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('class_B1');
            for(var i in checkboxes)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
        function selectAllB2(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('class_B2');
            for(var i in checkboxes)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
        function selectAllC1(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('class_C1');
            for(var i in checkboxes)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
        function selectAllC2(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('class_C2');
            for(var i in checkboxes)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
        function selectAllD1(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('class_D1');
            for(var i in checkboxes)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
        function selectAllD2(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('class_D2');
            for(var i in checkboxes)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }
        function selectAllD3(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('class_D3');
            for(var i in checkboxes)
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
        }

        var show = true;

        function showCheckboxes() {
            var checkboxes =
                document.getElementById("checkBoxes");

            if (show) {
                checkboxes.style.display = "block";
                show = false;
            } else {
                checkboxes.style.display = "none";
                show = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
   ```

Comment: I suggest for you to use a select box with enabled multiple selection instead of a lot of checkboxes with same name. Look for it: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/

Comment: @AdamP. looks good, but is it possible to create a loyout similar to my layout there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your Confirm button, to `type="button"` and add an id `id="confirm"`

And add a JS click event handler for this button:

`$('#confirm').on('click',function(){ console.log($('form').serializeArray()); });` 
Now when checkboxes selected and click the Confirm button, the form data will appear in the console like this:
[image: my sample]

And here is a sample of backend processing (`var_dump($_POST);`) result:
[image: var_dump($_POST) output]

Comment: Thank you for your time, but i change only `id="confirmQ"` and it does not work, even with i do not add that`Q` there, no action after pressing the button. I updated main post with whole code.

Comment: Do you open the console (developer tools)? I forget to tell you, you need to include jquery.js in the head section

Comment: I am getting this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    <anonymous> file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/a/index.html:155` in console for the line where is `<script> $('#confirmQ').on('click',function(){ console.log($('form').serializeArray()); });</script>`
I downloaded jquery from their website and call it from head section with: `<script>src="jquery-3.5.1.js"</script>`

Comment: your script tag is broken, correct tag is: <script src="jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

Comment: I make a short video from working code and result here: https://youtu.be/EqPwVC7P9zs

Comment: because i do not have that 2 lines of code what you have in script part, i believe it was not formated so nicely, but i received now this:
` array(1) { ["aisle"]=> array(8) { [0]=> string(3) "107" [1]=> string(3) "108" [2]=> string(3) "114" [3]=> string(3) "115" [4]=> string(3) "116" [5]=> string(3) "117" [6]=> string(3) "118" [7]=> string(3) "119" } } `

seems to work, but still not sure how to transfer this to the checkbox.value

Comment: Where would you like to transfer? To the backend (php)? In my video represent it: `$('form').submit();`where handle the confirm button, serializeArray is not necessary for submit, this is only used for presenting the form data in client console

Comment: I manage to get what i was looking for, thanks to your `.serializeArray()` as i looked it up and there it was, how to send it to any element of website. I got just trivial issue that after Loop it adds ", "  and that is not good, I am not sure how to amend this one.
And it stopped closing dropdown list after I change the code.

Comment: I edited your code to fixed value string chain building issue, this apper when a trusted member approved it

Comment: thank you. I just got to work, and tried to inplement this dropdown in the website itself. I lost ability to get any data from the array. The function for collecting array to the Text box works, but it does not show any values, i tried it also with Console but no values either.
I inserted that  original dropdown into another form, it is now form within the form. Can this be an issue? Even when i am calling the dropdown form by its ID in the function?
here is the whole page if you have time to see it. https://pastebin.com/ay4FnjuR

Comment: Your code currently includes the zone labels too. For submit the form just add a `$('form').submit();` line at the end the core of confirm handler

Comment: I added it there, i believe i must change the `'form'` to represent correct form id? as i did in this code.
`$('#confirmQ').on('click',function(){   
  
 $('#aisle_selection').submit();

 var x = $("#aisle_selection").serializeArray();

 $("#aisle_selectbox").empty();
$.each(x, function(i, field){  
  $("#aisle_selectbox").append(field.value + ", ");
   });`

Comment: Now in your pastebin I see you used SQL queries in input values (ordering results), that is very dangerous, the input values are simply overwritable from browser developer toolbar, instead of these unsecure mode handle these functionalities in the backend, e.g.: `if(isset[$_POST['order_bys'] && $_POST['order_bys'] == "Stock_level_Asc"){ $sql_query .= "ORDER BY iv.item_qtty asc"; }`

Comment: No, submit() must be the last command in this function! MY working code here: https://pastebin.com/ZEJNUsxe

Comment: I found the issue, i cannot have form within the form, once i places the dropdown form out  of main form it  started working again. Thank you for help. https://pastebin.com/udC8vcpf